# My Css and HTML aren't linking together and I'm not sure why

Tags: html, css

Hey here's my html code ,  I haven't even bothered started to write my site yet because I can't connect to the css and I have no clue why. I'm using Aptana studio 3 btw

```
<head>
    <title>blah blah blah</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website/style.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>blah blah blah</h1> 
    <div>Just a row of information. Yeah nothing more </div>
    </body>
```

I've read a few of the questioned related but nothing helped me. If I read correctly they need to be in the same root folder to be connected to one another correct ? I'm a beginner at this but I didn't think I was going to have this much trouble already.

Comment: So, your `index.html` is in the web root folder, and then there's *another* folder under that called `website`, which contains `style.css`? If they're in the same folder, just use `href="style.css"`

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be in the same root folder but relative to where you're pointing to. Currently it looks like you have: root/index.html and root/website/style.css, is this correct?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what it was. I had the extra website/ and it wasn't needed. Thanks for the fast response guys. I'll be asking a lot of questions with this.

Comment: Tip:  open up firebug or view the source code on the page, and click on the path to your css file to see **why** it isn't linking up.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a specific CSS folder, inside the folder where your HTML files are. (html > css)

Then you will can call your CSS like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/your-file.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't need to be in the same folder, but the CSS does need to be where it is being called from.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website/style.css" />
```

This is telling the browser that your site is set up thus:

```
wwwroot (or whatever folder the site is in)
 |_ index.htm (or whatever the page you pulled the above code from)
 |_ website
    |_ style.css
```

If you're going to use a relative URL (like you are in the code supplied), then you need to make sure that the path is correct relative to the file your link is in.

If that's going to get ... interesting ... then you are probably going to be better off giving a fully qualified URL for the CSS file, e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
                  href="http://www.example.com/folderwithcss/style.css" />
```

Note:

- The line break is not strictly needed, I'm just not a fan of side scrolling in an answer when it can be avoided.
- Please don't actually use a folder called "folderwithcss"... just use "css" or "resources" or some similar depending on what you do/don't toss in there.